# Is sortBy of the mori library stable?

Tags: javascript, sorting, mori

Is sortby of the mori library

http://swannodette.github.io/mori/#sortBy

stable?

(Stable as in this sense : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/247440/what-does-it-mean-for-a-sorting-algorithm-to-be-stable)

Comment: What's the exact problem? The functions seems ok and I don't see any issues on github related to sortBy

Comment: @wookieb : updated the question

Comment: @wookieb: A stable sort algorithm guarantees that two items with equal sorting weight appear in the original order after being sorted.

Comment: Thanks for clarfication. Didn't know the term in this context. Answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - yes

It's not described in the docs but... Mori uses sort-by from Clojure Script (there is no other implementation of sortBy in mori repository)
https://github.com/swannodette/mori/blob/master/src/mori.cljs#L30

```
(mori-export sortBy cljs.core/sort-by)
```

the implementation of sort-by from cljs
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L2328

which uses Google Closure Library that claims to be stable
https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/array/array.js#L1144

Comment: Good answer if true, but is mori using sort-by from clojurescript?  Mori is a port of clojurescript, while clojurescript is compiled into js.   Two different things.  But fair enough : since it is a port of sortby of cljs and that one is stable, the changes are the mori one also is.

Comment: Also. Mori isn't port of clojurescript. It basically exports clojure script code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test script to check the stability:

```js
// Perform tests (increase number for thorough test):
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // Create random array of zeroes and ones, and pair them with a sequence number:
    const arr = Array.from(Array(10), (_, i) => [+(Math.random()>=0.5), i]);
    console.log('in: ', JSON.stringify(arr));
    // Sort by the 0 and 1 values:
    const result = mori.toJs(mori.sortBy(v => v[0], arr));
    console.log('out:', JSON.stringify(result));
    // Throw an error if the sequence number of equal values is not increasing
    result.reduce( (a, b) => {
        if (a[0] === b[0] && a[1] > b[1]) throw "Not stable!";
        return b;
    } );
}
console.log('is stable');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mori/0.3.2/mori.min.js"></script>
```

When trying this with large arrays and many times, it turns out the sort always keeps the original order for values that have the same sort order. So it is stable.

Comment: Nice one ! However no proof of stability strictly spoken.  Even though large numbers make it 'as good as a proof' , it is only 'as good as a proof' on the system it's tested on.

Comment: True, but a claim is also not a proof :-) The ultimate proof would be a [formal verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) of the actual implementation code.

Comment: Indeed, a perfect answer is certainly not yet supplied, I am still waiting on David Nolen to pass by :)